# Ubuntu 12.04 Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

i am new to Ubuntu. And i have been trying to install a new version of the nvidia drivers.

When i do so, the resolution changes to 800*600 and i am unable to change it back. the reason i believe i need new drivers is because i tried to install World of warcraft and i manage to do so via Wine altough i were experiencing som graphical bugs.

under "settings/Details/Graphics" it says "Driver Unknown"

I tried to download the driver from nvidias homepage(but i did't know how to install it:( ) Is it possible my graphical bugs have something do to with wine? Or is this do to my drivers? And is there a way to get the "settings/details/Graphics right?

Answer (score 1):

Enter into terminal `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*.`
Now reboot see if the resolution is fixed if not try changing it again from the display app.

Now lets try the nvidia drivers again `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.
Reboot if the screen gets big again try changing the resolution from the nvidia settings app

Answer (score 1):

In my case installing the current driver only made my desktop resolution worse.  The solution was simple.  I moved the monitor output to the DVI-I and all is well.  Why it does not work with DVI-Digital I can't say.  Hope this helps someone else!
   nVidia 650Ti  x58,i920, 12GB RAM, Gateway 1920x1200 monitor.

Comment: Those are some seriously powerful specs! :o